# Increase performance of SELECT COUNT(*) with WHERE clause in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite

I'm trying to build a leaderboard in which I'm using this query:

```sql
SELECT id, COUNT(type) FROM Data 
WHERE UPPER(type) = $1 AND id != '123123123123' 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Which takes about 8-10 seconds in my table `Data` consisting of approx. 4 million rows and growing by 100,000+ rows per day.

The table also has a UNIQUE INDEX which is unique when combining values from 2 different columns — `code` and `version`.

What can I do to increase the speed and performance of this query?

I've considered building a counter for each user's rows, but that wouldn't be very intuitive as the `type` can differ between 100+ values. I've also tried adding an index on `id` and `type` which still takes after 8-10 seconds if not more.

Comment: Have you got any indexes on this table?

Comment: Yes, let me update the question with this information.

Comment: You need an index on `id, type`

Answer (score 0):

keep a running total on that column, use an insert trigger

[Trigger for updating total records on both insert and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613864/trigger-for-updating-total-records-on-both-insert-and-delete)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "keep a running total on that column"?

Comment: when the table is updated (the reason you need new total), update a TOTAL column in some other table, then when you need that total, just select * on table_count.totval or whatever table to keep the running totals

Comment: don't stay lost, I will do it for you , send details

Comment: I'm not sure this would work since type can differ in so many values. Wouldn't I need to make a column for each value of type?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options with different performance benefits and trade-offs.

But all work by maintaining a second summary table of the count of each value of the `type` by `id` columns. (basically you are storing in a table in the database the output of your query you want to improve the performance of, this is for use later use using a simple and quick query)

So as you have not given exactly how to create the tables you are using I had to deduce from you query as an example

So for `Data` table created by

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Data" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "type"  TEXT
)
```

You would create a second table to store the count by

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Data_summary" (
    "type"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "data_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "total_count"   INTEGER,
    UNIQUE ("type", "data_id")
)
```

(as you group by `id` that has to be part of the Unique constraints as well as `type`)

The query that you want to speed up would then be

```sql
SELECT * FROM Data_summary WHERE data_id != 123123123123
    ORDER BY total_count DESC LIMIT 10
```

All have the trade-off of storage space cost over query speed, plus there is extra work need to maintain the summary table, to which there are various strategies are detailed below.
It does not matter how many different values of the contents of the `type` and `id` columns you have, that just makes the `Data_summary` table bigger to store

Options:
**1)** Update the summary table using a `Trigger` as suggested by @stephenmwyatt22-w
(but I give actual details in my answer of a working example).

So you would create a trigger like:-

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_summary AFTER INSERT ON Data
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Data_summary (type, data_id, total_count)
    -- If Insert is success this is a new value of type so count is 1
    VALUES (NEW.type, NEW.id, 1)
    -- If value of type/id combo exists then there will be a conflict (this requires sqlite version 3.24.0 or later)
    ON CONFLICT(type, data_id)
    DO UPDATE SET total_count=total_count+1
        WHERE type == NEW.type AND data_id == NEW.id;
END;
```

So every time an insert is done into the `Data` a second insert/update is automatically done to the `Data_summary` table (If the value of type/id combo has never been seen before it sets the `total_count` to be 1 else there is a `CONFLICT` on the insert because it is set to be UNIQUE combination and thus uses the [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_UPSERT.html) process to insert `UPDATE` the `total_count` + 1

A drawback of this approach is that if you already have the `Data` table with data it in then you will "bootstrap" the `Data_summary` table with some one off "update" sql statements in code (something like `INSERT INTO ...`) to count existing data before the `TRIGGER` takes over maintaining the `Data_summary` table.

**Update:**
[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8306b8709c9b38dea9741dfe152298e9)

**2)**
Instead of using a trigger to update the `Data_summary` table, you could do "batch" updates. For this you would also need to have a UNIQUE index column integer that is Auto Incremented or something like a DATE+TIME column to maintain a pointer to where the where the `Data_summary` was last updated to (this pointer of "last update to" needs to be stored somewhere like a third table)

When you want do an "Update" of `Data_summary` table you would run a query like your original but with an additional WHERE clause to limit the query to only  on "NEW" rows in the `Data` table that you have not already summarised in the `Data_summary` table.
This would use a similar `ON CONFLICT` to insert new `id` and `type` combinations or update existing count of combinations if they exist already.

The batch update could be done as a background task or just before the results are needed as the expensive query would only be on "new" data plus the simple query.

I won't give an example for as this is all the SQL is very similar to the Option 1) example.